# Convert datetime to unix timestamp in python

Tags: python, datetime

When I try to convert from UTC timestamp to normal date and add the right timezone I can't find the way to convert the time back to Unix timestamp.

What am I doing worng?

```
utc_dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(self.__modified_time)
from_zone = tz.tzutc()
to_zone = tz.tzlocal()

utc = utc_dt.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
central = utc.astimezone(to_zone)
```

Central is equal to

> 2015-10-07 12:45:04+02:00

This is what I have when running the code, and I need to convert the time back to timestamp.

Comment: could this work https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm

Comment: Yes what i need, :) pls make a aswer with it, :)

Comment: related: [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8777753/4279)

Comment: if there is no error then `self.__modified_time` is the unix timestamp that you want. Why do you want to recompute it?

Comment: unrelated: it seems that your code uses `dateutil.tz`: beware, [utc -> local conversions may fail with `dateutil` timezones](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/112)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from calendar import timegm

utc_dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(self.__modified_time)
from_zone = tz.tzutc()
to_zone = tz.tzlocal()

utc = utc_dt.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
central = utc.astimezone(to_zone)
unix_time_central = timegm(central.timetuple())
```

Comment: downvote. It is incorrect. `timegm()` expect UTC time, not central. You could test it by comparing `unix_time_central` to `self.__modified_time` (they should be equal).

Answer (score 0):

To get an aware datetime that represents time in your local timezone that corresponds to the given Unix time (`self.__modified_time`), you could pass the local timezone to `fromtimestamp()` directly:

```
from datetime import datetime
import tzlocal # $ pip install tzlocal

local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone() # pytz tzinfo
central = datetime.fromtimestamp(self.__modified_time, local_timezone)
# -> 2015-10-07 12:45:04+02:00
```

To get the Unix time back in Python 3:

```
unix_time = central.timestamp()
# -> 1444214704.0
```

`unix_time` is equal to `self.__modified_time` (ignoring floating point errors and "right" timezones). [To get the code for Python 2 and more details, see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279).

Answer (score -1):

**Arrow** ( http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/ ) appears to be the ultimate Python time-related library

```
import arrow
ts = arrow.get(1455538441)
# ts -> <Arrow [2016-02-15T12:14:01+00:00]>
ts.timestamp
# 1455538441
```